# Using redux's useDispatch in a custom hook yields an error

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to implement useDispatch in a custom hook that dispatches a redux action, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

**CODE:**

modules file

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'

export function useFetchEvents() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const { items, loading } = useSelector(state => state.events)
  if (items.length === 0) {
    dispatch(requestEvents(true))
  }
}
```

functional component

```
import { useFetchEvents } from '../../../modules/events'

const FrontPage = () => {
  return(
    <div>
      Front Page
      <button onClick={useFetchEvents}>
        Fetch events
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default FrontPage
```

I've seen the error and read the rules regarding hooks, but if I understand it correctly I should be able to use useDispatch in a custom hook. Like in the following working examples:

https://github.com/mikeour/drinks_drinks_drinks/blob/master/src/hooks/index.js

Comment: You can't use ```useFetchEvents``` inside the return statement

Comment: That would make dispatching actions from buttons very complicated. Is there a reference for that?

Comment: Why your hook don't have a return statement? All the hooks return something

Comment: @mthrsj The return is not really the point of my example, the hook needs to update the store that's the main point.

Comment: @istvan Taking the hook out of the return indeed solved it. But then how do I deal with situations of onChange or onClick, where I want the user interaction to dispatch an action?

Comment: "Only call hooks at the top level" https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#targetText=Don't%20call%20Hooks%20inside,each%20time%20a%20component%20renders.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Then number of hook calls in each invocation should be the same (that's why you are not allowed to call hooks inside `if` statements).

To achieve this `useFetchEvents` hook should return a function that can be conditionally called, e.g. onClick

change `useFetchEvents` like so:

```
export function useFetchEvents() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const { items, loading } = useSelector(state => state.events)
  return () => {
      if (items.length === 0) {
        // Redux action. requestEvents returns object with type.
        dispatch(requestEvents(true))
      }
  }
}
```

Then in your component do this:

```
const FrontPage = () => {
  const fetchEvents = useFetchEvents()

  return(
    <div>
      Front Page
      <button onClick={() => fetchEvents()}>
        Fetch events
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: @S.Schenk added an explanation